# Automation tool for Plone edition

Tags: plone

I am registered to the editor profile a portal written in Plone. I received the task of changing multiple links (over 1000) to their new addresses.

Did the following:

1. I saved all the pages that needed correction to a folder (by copy & paste);
2. wrote a C program to find all occurrences of URLs to be replaced;
3. placed in a text file the old URLs and their substitutes URLs (one line below another: old URL, new URL, the old URL, new URL, the old URL, ...);
4. then another program made the appropriate substitutions.
5. after that, just reset the pages (copy & paste).
   It happens that spent a lot of time in steps 1 and 5. 
   I wonder if there was any way to automate this procedure? In other words: is there any Plone tool that automatically save all pages of a portal in a computer folder and then do the opposite (from the computer to the server)? I have searched a lot and did not find.

Comment: if you know that for example http://old-domain.com/some-folder needs to be replaced by http://new-domin.com/another-folder/ you can use one of these packages: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/c2.app.replaceword/ or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.searchandreplace

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Although it seems to me that they are really good for the administrators of a site, I don´t think it will be working for an editor. So if there is really no way to do the massive changes without having the administrator's rights, as I guess, I intend to sugest them (the administrators of my site) to try one of the solutions here supplied.

Comment: The massive download part of the issue I have already solved by developing a web crawler in Java+JSoap. 
The basic knowledge:

1. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
2. http://www.mballem.com/post/capturando-conteudo-html-com-jsoup/ (in portuguese)
Now I need to know how to upload the modified files. The problem is that I am not experienced in Java nor in network connections.

Comment: For administrators:
https://plone.org/products/massloader

Answer (score 2):

If these links point to old locations in the same site, you could just use `plone.app.redirector` to redirect them to the new locations:

```
from plone.app.redirector.interfaces import IRedirectionStorage
from zope.component import getUtility

storage = getUtility(IRedirectionStorage)
paths = [('old/path/1', 'new/path/1'), ('old/path/2', 'new/path/2'), ]

for old_path, new_path in paths:
    storage.add(old_path, new_path)
```

This way, you don't have to edit every single page that contains a old link.

More info: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.redirector/

Comment: Don't forget Products.RedirectionTool

Comment: Thanks, tcurvelo!
The links are external links, that changed from www to others initial characteres.

Answer (score 1):

If new there some kind of relations between the format of old URL's to new ones, using [rt.bulkmodify](http://plone.org/products/rt.bulkmodify) may help a lot.

Comment: In this especific case, the new links are totally different from the old ones. That's because I had to put them in pairs lines (old, new, old, new...) in one file.

Answer (score 1):

All automated solutions need an administrator, since they involve installing add-ons.

Having that as a pre-requisite, if you for some reason need to *programatically* change these links without creating a full blown package to do it (or if the suggestions gave here won't solve your specific problem), you could interact with your [ZODB in command line](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/commandline.html) with a simple Python script that would do it for you.

**Always** backup your ZODB before doing these operations.

Comment: Although I'm not an administrator by this time, may be this suggestions could solve others users that have the same problem. Thanks!